# VueJS : how to set a default value of a key / value in a prop of type array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning Vue JS and I am creating my components.
I'm stuck on an issue.

I would like to have my component taking in params an array of object like that :

```
data() {
    return {
        items: [
            {
                text: 'Admin',
                href: '#'
            },
            {
                text: 'Manage',
                href: '#'
            },
            {
                text: 'Library',
                active: true
            }
        ]
    }
```

So, I tried to implement my component with props :

```
props: {
        items: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
       }
```

However, I have no idea how to say that : if items does not contains active key, then it should have a false default value.

If you have any advices/links or explanations, I will be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `computed` property which will fill-in those `active: false` by default, and override it with the provided items:

```
props: {
  items: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
},
computed: {
  normalizedItems() {
    return this.items.map(x => ({ active: false, ...x }));
  }
}
```

You would then use `normalizedItems` in your template instead of `items`